# Flux is giving empty or partial response some times in spring webflux

Tags: spring-webflux, flux

we have implemented an API in spring webflux which retrieves the data from elastic search and return the response to consumer ResposeEntity<Flux> which is giving emprty or partial response some times. and response size is around 100KB

Attaching the code snippet:

**controller**

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/test")
    public ResponseEntity<Flux<Product>> getresult(@Valid @RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO,ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {


        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.get(requestDTO), HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

**serviceimpl**

```
return elasticSearchRepository.search(searchRequest)
                            .doOnError(err -> log.error(Constants.Log.ES_ERROR_MESSAGE, err.getMessage()))
                            .map(pp -> serviceImplHelper.makeProductDTO(pp, ma,
                                    intermediateObject.getMapping())

                            ).log();
```

**elasticSearchRepositoryimpl**

```
public Flux<ProductPage> search(SearchRequest searchRequest) {
        return reactiveElasticsearchClient.search(searchRequest)

                .map(r -> mapper.convertValue(r.getSourceAsMap(), ProductPage.class))
                .groupBy(p -> p.getMetaData().getCId())
                .flatMap(g -> g.reduce((a,
                        b) -> a.getMetaData().getCDate().compareTo(b.getMetaData().getCDate()) > 0 ? a : b))
                .switchIfEmpty(
                        Flux.defer(() -> Flux.error(new NoDataException(Constants.Error._NOT_FOUND))));
```